# Remove (or throttle) fan on eMac

Tags: imac, temperature

I'm replacing the HDD  with a SSD on an eMac (1 GHz). I get a headache from the  loud fan noise. A friend who does hardware repairs said the fan is there mainly because of the HDD, so I should then be able to disconnect the fan. Can someone with knowledge and experience with this confirm?

If the machine will fail without the fan, we plan to throttle the fan, ie. adjust its supplied power based on the measured temperature in the cabinet. Please share any knowledge/experience with this.

Comment: I would suggest the power supply produces most of the heat...

Comment: Don't remove the fan. Although SSDs generally generate less heat than HDDs, as SolarMike indicates, there are other components inside which generate heat as well. Seeing that the eMac is a rather antiquarian device, I would suspect it generates more heat than more modern devices, but this is just a guess. From your question, I can't see a overwhelmingly crucial reason to remove the fan at all. When I maintained a fleet of eMacs in the early part of this century, they ran pretty hot, and it wasn't solely the HDD that generated the heat. Kudos on using an eMac!

Comment: Why, oh why, would you do this??  Fans do one critical thing:  they move air.  They either pull air (cool) air in or push (hot) air out.  You have an eMac which is an old CRT (*vacuum tube*) based computer along with a ton of old components.  These things generate heat.  Keeping it cool will only prolong the life of the eMac.

Comment: How's your results ? I want to remove Tube monitor, for drop weight, some heating and remove danger parts :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fan is making enough noise to give you a headache it's because the bearing has worn out.

Removing the fan is not a good idea.  Fans in computers either pull in cool air or expel warm air.  The fact that this fan was close to the drive doesn't negate the fact that it wasn't displacing the "other" warm ambient air *around* the drive.

You have three options:

- Replace the fan.  A quick [search on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=emac%20fan%20assembly&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=922-5866) shows there are still fans available for the eMac.
- Replace the motor.  The good news is that the fan motor and blades aren't so custom as you would think.  The fan PN# is 4710KL-04W-B56 and [can also be found on eBay quite easily](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=4710KL-04W-B56).  You can disassemble the fan, extract the motor/blades and replace it.
- Replace the bearing.  These older fan assemblies could actually be taken apart (if you're careful).  Simply replace the bearing assembly (you'll need ID and OD measurements) and purchase a bearing online.

Comment: The fan makes a normal (but high) swoosh. I don't think the fan is broken or worn. Will your suggestions get the fan noise completely silent? (I simply can't have any hardware that makes constant fan noises...)

Comment: There's no fan that can be "completely silent."  At the very minimum, you're moving air with blades which causes buffeting resulting in noise.  Remember, CRTs were *hot* to begin with (but "dumb"), Apple adding a computer (CPU, I/O, networking, graphics, etc.) and that generated even more heat.  Excessive heat shortens the life of electronic components and you want to do everything you can to mitigate that.  A new fan/motor will make it quieter, but not "completely silent."

Comment: I'll just have to try, then. Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: I bought a "brand new" eMac cooler from eBay of course, but it's not help me, noise present here too, it's because (as I suppose) from fan form, and flow direction... eMac through out air-flow. I think eMac doesn't see temperature of devices at all that is the main reason wrong speed provided (e.g. PWM control). If you little bit time place your hand on exhaust hole on backside of your eMac (bottom) you can turn slow down your cooler and noise will be less painful :) But, it's not good idea for remove cooler or close this hole at all :)